# Is it possible, In JSP, to print the value of a variable whose name is in another variable?

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee

The problem i am having is like this
there is variable

```
<core:set var="type">*one of: load,migrate, or ...* </core:set>
```

and the value of **load, migrate,** is a map. Now, i want to print the value of these based on the type? Is it possible at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will achieve the same effect as @Chii's answer:

```
<c:set var="attributeName" value="foo"/>

<%
  out.println(pageContext.getAttribute(attributeName) + " = " + pageContext.getAttribute(pageContext.getAttribute(attributeName)));
%>
```

This, nasty as it is, will list all the attributes in the *page scope* if you need to do that:

```
<%
  for (String attributeName : pageContext.getAttributeNamesInScope(PageContext.PAGE_SCOPE))
  {
    out.println(attributeName + " = " + pageContext.getAttribute(attributeName));
  }
%>
```

Don't think there's a way to do this in JSTL, but you normally only need this during debugging so I don't have such a problem with the scriptlet code.

Comment: @Chii - yeah, scriptlets aren't the prettiest of things, but you can always write a custom tag to hide it all :-)

Answer (score 1):

if they are not in a map, its hard.

I assume you wanted to do it the way perl works: where you could type

```
$foo = "stuff";
$varName = "foo";
print $$varName; #prints "stuff"
```

That doesnt work in jsp.

If its a map,you can do `${mapValue[key]}`. Info on [this page](http://java.sun.com/j2ee/1.4/docs/tutorial/doc/JSPIntro7.html) near the Variables section

Comment: All the variables in a JSP are in the equivalent of a map - the javax.servlet.jsp.PageContext, which provides the methods you'll need to query the variable names and their values for each scope.

Comment: you are correct, i wanted the way u did this in perl, also the value of *stuff* is map, **suff** is not in any map.